# Ejecutar script php en segundo plano (windows / linux)

Tags: php

Estoy intentado ejecutar un `script de php` en segundo plano.

La ejecución de comando funciona correctamente en el servidor de producción `Linux`,  pero no el de servidor de desarrollo `Windows`

Tengo el siguiente código :

verifico en que servidor estamos  esto devuelve `LIN` o `WIN`

```
$sistema = strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3));
```

Dirección del script a ejecutar

```
$direccion = RAIZ."/admin/proyectos/generar.php";
```

Ahora ejecuto el comando :

**LINUX** (funciona correctamente)

```php
if($sistema == "LIN"){
    exec("php ".$direccion . " Nproyect=".$Nproyect . " Temail=".$Temail. " > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
}
```

**WINDOWS** (no funciona)

```
if($sistema == "WIN"){
   pclose(popen("start /B php ".$direccion . " Nproyect=".$Nproyect . " Temail=".$Temail ,  "r"));
}
```

Archivo de destino : actualmente solo obtengo las variables  y las imprimo en un txt
pero posterior mente hará un proceso bastante grande.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=="") $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]= "/var/www/vhosts/tacktil.com/httpdocs";
 include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/php/lib.plib";

 parse_str($argv[0], $params);
 $argv = preg_replace("//");
 $smg = "el proyecto es " . $Nproyect . " el correo es ". $Temail;
 file_put_contents("prueba.txt",$smg);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi caso siempre me ha funcionado practicamente lo mismo que tienes:

```
$command = 'start /b php.exe '.$el_script_php.' '.$arg1.' '.$arg2 ... ;
pclose(popen($command, 'r'));
```

Ahora algunas consideraciones:

1- Si observas, $command tiene como ejecutable **php.exe**, por lo tanto asegúrate que `X:\La\Ruta\De\php.exe` esté incluida en PATH de las variables de entorno de sistema. En caso contrario, supongo que también funcionaría poniendo la ruta absoluta del ejecutable.

2- Verificar el parámetro `register_argc_argv=On` en **php.ini** para que el script pueda [recibir argumentos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.argv.php) por comando.